# iterate over chunks of an array using ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, grouping, templating

My controller grabs people from the server:

```
$scope.people = [person1, person2, person3, person4, person5,...]
```

My template needs to display three people per line. For example if it was a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>person1</td><td>person2</td><td>person3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>person4</td><td>person5</td><td>person6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I wasn't sure how to conditionally apply the `<tr>` when `$index % 3 == 0` or what the best practices are. I know how to do this by adding grouping logic to the controller but I thought it would be best to keep design logic out of the controller.

Comment: This is an awesome solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/11058532/304319

Comment: @sza thanks for the link I'm looking through it now. I should have mentioned I *may* need filters to work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After years of angular experience, It's obvious that the best way to do this is to split the array into chunks in the controller. Each time the original array is modified, update the chunked array.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an existing way to do what you are saying with a table. The easiest way to do what you want is to use divs with fixed widths, so that they will auto-wrap after three.

Here is an example:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="TableCtrl" class="my-table">
        <span ng-repeat="person in people" class="person">{{person}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-table{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.person{
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('TableCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.people = ['Aaron', 'Abraham', 'Adam', 'Aristotel', 'Aziel', 'Azod', 'Azood'];

});
```

Working copy: http://jsfiddle.net/ZX43D/

Comment: Thanks - Alas I was hoping angularjs would have a simple way. I'll try use CSS as you suggest - In reality I have a special DOM element (not a <tr>) so it will be tricky using straight CSS. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current solution (It's **O(N^2)** so doesn't scale for large lists).

**Template:**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="testing">
        <div ng-repeat="_ in items">
            <span ng-show="($parent.$index % 3 == 0) && ($parent.$index + 3 > $index) && ($parent.$index <= $index)" ng-repeat="item in items">
                <span ng-show="1">
                    {{item}}
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('myapp', []);

function testing($scope){
    $scope.items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f','g'];
}
```

**Result:**

```
a b c
d e f
g
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/LjX3m/

**Conclusion:**

I'll probably try use CSS for this as @aaronfrost mentions. (However it may not be possible since some wrapping divs may be required for each chunk).