# AngularJS ng-repeat grid of two divs per row

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to load data from an array and display two divs per row.

Eg: say there are 8 objects.
I want them to appear in four rows of two

1 2

3 4

5 6

7 8

Code:

```
<div ng-repeat="accObj in accountsArr" width="100%">
    <div class="col" width="100%">
    <div  ng-if="$even" style="width:50%;height:70px;background-color:red">
    {{accObj.account}}<br>
    {{accObj.type}}
    </div>
    <div  ng-if="$odd" style="width:50%;height:70px;background-color:yellow">
    {{accObj.account}}<br>
    {{accObj.type}}
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

This is how my code works at the moment. 
[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lTPoJM6ZnykkHD2djejC?p=preview)

Can someone please guide me how to get the desired result?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564888/iterate-over-chunks-of-an-array-using-ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is CSS issue - Just add `float:left;` to `style` of both divs & it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply simple CSS to keep them side by side.There are multiple ways to achieve it.
One of them is to use `<span>` tag:

```
<span style="margin:4px">{{accObj.account}}</span>
<span style="margin:4px">{{accObj.type}}</span>
```

[Example here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/zt3tAK2pK2L5rZG60xIY?p=preview)

Use margin of your choice.