# Display or generate collection elements into a table in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

$scope.values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

How do I generate below html from the above data in the below format, using angular js. using ng-repeat etc..

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There are numerous ways to approach this. Please show what you have tried

Comment: @user3759612 Were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

This is one method:

**JS:**

```
$scope.values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="value in values" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">
         <td>{{values[$index]}}</td>
         <td>{{values[$index+1]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Because the values is odd, the last  will be empty. If you'd prefer to only output one TD when the values are odd you can simply add a ng-if to the TDs so that they are not displayed if they have no value.

Though, I would personally restructure the data before it gets to the view. Break the values apart into rows and then loop through the data set to get the rows, and then loop through the rows to get the individual values.

Far more information and options can be found (on SO already) here: [How would I use AngularJS ng-repeat with Twitter Bootstrap's scaffolding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056819/how-would-i-use-angularjs-ng-repeat-with-twitter-bootstraps-scaffolding)